# Reversing complex Admin URLs from templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I find myself needing a bit more flexibility than what I understand I can do based on the Django documentation for reversing Admin URLs. I'm doing things like:

```
{% url admin:billing_creditcardtoken_add %}?customer={{ user.id }}
```

This works, but it feels like I should be able to do it without leaving the template tags.

If I want to find all `CreditCardToken` objects from the billing application that belong to the current user, I find myself doing:

```
{% url admin:billing_creditcardtoken %}?customer={{ user.id }}
```

...but this fails altogether. Is there a more elegant way of getting these URLs?

Comment: "without leaving the template tags." I don't understand this. "It fails" define "fails", do you see an exception, traceback ?

Comment: if you want to get the url from a tag with two parameters (page & user id), you have to write your own. But the final URL placed in your HTML will be exactly the same.

Comment: @jpic Yes, when it fails, it says `Reverse for 'billing_creditcardtoken' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Comment: This means that there are no url registered with name 'billing_creditcardtoken', maybe a typo ? double check the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at this the wrong way. While:

```
{% url admin:billing_creditcardtoken_add %}?customer={{ user.id }}
```

...might be somewhat ugly, the only thing added syntax would serve to do is try to construct a query string, which isn't something one reverses URLs to do normally anyway. So this is an acceptable method of accomplishing this task.

What I was looking for in the second turned out to be:

```
{% url admin:billing_creditcardtoken_changelist %}?customer={{ user.id }}
```

...`changelist`, as it turns out, does not show a history of changes, but creates a list of possible items to change. Adding the query string applies the proper filter I needed.

Comment: Note that you could make a template filter to encapsulate url generation with GET parameters if you had to code the url twice.